# $u_{xx} + 2u_{xy} + u_{yy} = x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

$u_{xx} + 2u_{xy} + u_{yy} = x$ it has more than one particular solution. How can we prove this? 
Can anyone help me out? Please be elaborate I am a first reader.

Comment: Find one particular solution by trying some simple polynomials (e.g. $Ax^3$ or $Bx^2y + Cy^3$ and solve for the constants). You can also write the PDE as $(\partial_x + \partial_y)(\partial_x + \partial_y)u = x$ and use this to show that if $u_0(x,y)$ is a particular solution then so is $u_0(x,y) + f(x-y)$ where $f$ is any differentiable function.

Comment: yes I can see that $\frac{1}{6}(x^3)$ is a Particular solution.. But I can not understand how to show it has many? @Winther

Comment: are u saying that $\frac{1}{6} (x^3)$ + f(x - y)$ is a particular solution where f is any differentiable function. That's why it has many particular solution?

Answer (score 1):

Following one of the comments, the PDE can be put into the following form:
$$(\partial_x+\partial_y)^2u=x \tag{*}$$
Let us propose the following change of variables:
$$\eta = x+y \qquad \xi=x-y$$
The derivatives $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ change accordingly:
$$\partial_x =\partial_x\eta\,\partial_\eta +\partial_x\xi\,\partial_\xi=\partial_\eta+\partial_\xi$$
$$\partial_y =\partial_y\eta\,\partial_\eta +\partial_y\xi\,\partial_\xi=\partial_\eta-\partial_\xi$$
Therefore the equation $(*)$ can be rewritten as follows:
$$\partial_\eta^2u=\frac{1}{2}(\eta+\xi)\tag{**}$$

The homogeneous solution $u_h$ of $(**)$ coincides with:
$$u_h=f(\xi)+g(\xi)\eta$$
Where $f$  and $g$ are two arbitrary functions.

For the particular solution $u_p$ we seek functions of the form:
$$u_p=a\eta^3+b\eta^2\xi$$
Plugging it into $(**)$ we obtain the constants $a$ and $b$
$$u_p=\frac{1}{12}\eta^3+\frac{1}{4}\eta^2\xi \tag{***}$$

From $(***)$ you can easily see that it has more than one particular solution. Recall that $\eta=x+y$ and $\xi=x-y$

Comment: $\frac{1}{6} x^3
+ f(x - y)$ is a particular solution where f is any differentiable function. That's why it has many particular solution. Can I conclude like this?@H B R

Comment: No this is not a particular solution. Please see where I say what is the particular solution.